# If a number cannot be...

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, square-numbers

*If there exists such a number which cannot be divided by some other number, which is equivalent to, or smaller than the square root of itself, it is a prime number.*

This is a rather trivial theorem but I would like to see different takes on proving this.

Comment: So, your statement is "if $d\not\mid n$ for $d > \sqrt{n}$ then $n$ is prime"?

Comment: Rather, "for $d \le \sqrt{n}$". Words are hard!

Comment: *Proof:* Left to reader. $\square$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $n$ is a positive integer such that for all $1<m\leq\sqrt{n}$, $m$ does not divide $n$. Suppose, to the contrary, that $n$ is not prime. Then there exist positive integers $a$ and $b$ greater than $1$ such that $ab=n$. Without loss of generality, suppose that $a$ is the smaller of the two. We know by hypothesis that $a>\sqrt{n}$, so $ab\geq a^2>n$. This is a contradiction, so $n$ must be prime.

Answer (score 1):

if $n$ is compound then $n=rs$ with $\min(r,s) \gt 1$

suppose $r \gt \sqrt{n}$ and $s \gt \sqrt{n}$

then $n = rs \gt \sqrt{n}\sqrt{n}=n$ a contradiction.

so if $n$ is compound we must have $\min(r,s) \le \sqrt{n}$